# Align span inside of div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I’m looking for a way to make sure that all label have the same space to the bottom border. (It should look like the image, and not like the fiddle)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musium/z7hL3any/)

Goal:

[image]

My CSS:

```
.outerDiv {
    text-align: center;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.innerDiv {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.errorLabel {
    background-color: #a90329;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .25em;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vertical-align doesn't have any affect due to your display: block.

Try changing vertical-align to "bottom" and display to "inline-block".  Then adjust your bottom margin/padding to your desire!

```
.errorLabel {
    background-color: #a90329;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .25em;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit:**
Added width: 100%; to keep the labels the full width.

As @RokoC.Buljan pointed out in the example in the comments, this can be accomplished with cleaner CSS.  My example above is just a few small modifications on the OP's original code (in case those classes are used elsewhere too).  :)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I’ve created a new fiddle to show your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/musium/L8nvcand/2/

Comment: Here's a demo of mine with a simplified CSS: http://jsbin.com/vekike/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: The text does not contain a background as is requested in the question, how is this the best answer so far?

Comment: @Burrito see my example. As OP uses `SPAN` there's no absolute need to position SPANs > absolute.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i would agree your answer is better than the one we are commenting under

Comment: @Burrito my answer would not add much > as a new answer, the principle is explained very well by Mike already. Mike is always welcome to post my example in his own answer. We're a *community* after all :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan touche!

Answer (score 1):

Absloute positioning would seem the logical choice.

```
.errorLabel {
    background-color: #a90329;
    padding: .2em .6em .2em;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .25em;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```css
.outerDiv {
  text-align: center;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.innerDiv {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative
}
.errorLabel {
  background-color: #a90329;
  padding: .2em .6em .2em;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .25em;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv"> <span>123123</span>
    <span class="errorLabel">OK</span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv"> <span>123123</span>
    <span class="errorLabel">Error2</span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv"> <span>123123</span>
    <span class="errorLabel">
            Line1<br/>
            Line2
        </span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv"> <span>123123</span>
    <span class="errorLabel">
            Line1<br />
            Line2
        </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fiddle with the bottom amount:

http://jsfiddle.net/z7hL3any/5/

add:

```
.errorLabel {
position: relative;
}

.innerDiv {  
position: absolute;
bottom: 5px;
width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    .errorLabel {
    background-color: #a90329;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em 0.3em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 100%;
}
```

.it should also work

Comment: Thanks, this works also. But only when I add ‘position:relative;’ to ‘innerDiv’: http://jsfiddle.net/musium/jn1cuzjj/